# Error from Branch: The network request was invalid

Tags: javascript, react-native, branch.io

I've got this error after add branch to my code **Error from Branch: The network request was invalid.**
[image: console]
and when I make a share from the app, it's generate a strange link, this's

> https://bnc.lt/a/key_test_yyyy?channel=WhatsApp&feature=share&type=0&duration=0&source=ios&data=eyJpZCI6IjV0NHFsRE5uRlBNWW9pMU96SVF0IiwiJG9nX2Rlc2NyaXB0aW9uIjoi2KfZhti22YXZiNinINmE2Yog2YHZiiAg2KrYrNix2KjYqSB0ZXN0IG1pbmltdW1tIHNlYXRzINmB2YogTWFra2FoINmK2YjZhSAyMDIwLzAxLzA5INi52YTZiSDZhdmG2LXYqSDYs9io2YTZgdiqIPCfjoggIiwiJGNhbm9uaWNhbF9pZGVudGlmaWVyIjoiRXhwZXJpZW5jZSIsInR5cGUiOiJleHBlcmllbmNlIn0%3D

and when I try to open it, I got this result!
[image: link]

**Environment**

- react-native: 0.59.8
- react-native-branch: ^3.0.0-beta.1

***Any Help on this, please?!***

Comment: I get thsisame error on flutter, and its says setp q and 2 are fine, and then it fails

Answer (score 0):

Please use the latest ReactNative Branch release which is 4.2.1 : https://github.com/BranchMetrics/react-native-branch-deep-linking-attribution/releases

This also requires you to use React Native version >= 0.60

This should most likely resolve your issue. Please be sure to follow the integration steps as mentioned in the Branch documentation : https://docs.branch.io/apps/react-native/